# Android Log Print CString

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

How to print CString from jni?
Usualy I use this code to print simple string:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
//...
__android_log_print( ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "msgTitle", "msg");
```

But how about CString format?
Error log:

```
cannot convert 'CString {aka CMSStringT<wchar_t>}' to 'char const*' for argument '3' to 'int __android_log_print(int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
```

I have already tried different casts, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: const char *samplestring = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, javaString, 0);
    printf("%s", sampleString);

Comment: @G3M: don't forget to `ReleaseStringUTFChars()` after.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a crossplatform log header like:

Logs.h

```
#       ifdef ANDROID
            // LOGS ANDROID
#           include <android/log.h>
#           define LOGV(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#           define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#           define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO   , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#           define LOGW(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN   , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#           define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR  , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#           define LOGSIMPLE(...)
#       else
            // LOGS NO ANDROID
#           include <stdio.h>
#           define LOGV(...) printf("  ");printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\t -  <%s> \n", LOG_TAG);
#           define LOGD(...) printf("  ");printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\t -  <%s> \n", LOG_TAG);
#           define LOGI(...) printf("  ");printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\t -  <%s> \n", LOG_TAG);
#           define LOGW(...) printf("  * Warning: "); printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\t -  <%s> \n", LOG_TAG);
#           define LOGE(...) printf("  *** Error:  ");printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\t -  <%s> \n", LOG_TAG);
#           define LOGSIMPLE(...) printf(" ");printf(__VA_ARGS__);
#       endif // ANDROID
```

And adding into JNI code something like:

main.c

```
#define LOG_TAG "JNIFILE"

main()
{
    LOGD("Test message");
}
```

Works for me.